# How to do the multiple enum expressions in a switch case for this matrix

Tags: debugging

[image]

I cannot figure out the switch cases for this output matrix.

I tried to use the indexes but it keeps giving me errors.

The only other way I can think is to do a big if else structure but that would be so messy looking.